# Python - compare list elements with dictionary elements

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I have a dictionary and a list. I need to compare the "id" tag of the dictionaries (integer) with the list elements. Something like this:

```
l = [[1], [7], [9]]

dict = {
"first":{
    "id": "0"
},
"second":{
    "id": "7"
},
"third":{
    "id": "4"
}
}

for i in l:
    for j in dict:
        if i == dict[j]["id"]:
            print("Yay!")
        else:
            print("Nay!")
```

I want to be able to check if any elements of list 'l' can be found in the "id" tags of dictionaries. How do I do that?

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Given the structure of `l`, you need to compare `str(i[0])` to the `id` value.

Comment: Additional suggestion - it does not appear there there's a particularly good reason to be holding each item in `l` within it's own list. If there's not other code reliant on it - just holding the values flat `l = [1,7,9]` would be easier.

Comment: @chepner I still get "Nay" with this: `if str(i[0]) == dict[j]["id"]:`

Comment: @Bilkokuya You are right but in my full code the `append` function adds all elements like that.

Comment: You get a `"Nay"` for each time an element is not equal. You are always looping over all of them. So with three elements in the list, you will get at best two `"Nay"` and one `"Yay"`, or three `"Nay"` if the element isn't matched by any of the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like so:

```
l = [[1], [7], [9]]

dict_ = {
         "first":{"id": "0"},
         "second":{"id": "7"},
         "third":{"id": "4"}
        }

ids = set(int(v['id']) for _, v in dict_.items())  # set of all ids for quick membership testing

l = [sublist for sublist in l if sublist[0] in ids]  # *
print(l)  # -> [[7]]
```

I am assuming that you want to modify (re-create) the `l` list with the items that meet your criteria.

---

Notes:

1. Do not use `dict` as a variable name. You are overwriting the Python built-in.
2. There is no point to have a list of lists with the sublists being 1-element long. Flatten it (`l = [1, 7, 9]`)

* alternatively, and if all elements in `l` are single-element lists, you can use the following which will most likely be significantly faster:

```
l = list(map(lambda x: [x], ids.intersection(x for y in l for x in y)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others please have ids as list instead list of lists. And how about the solution with `filter`

```
lst_ids = [1, 7, 9]

my_dict = {
"first":{
    "id": "0"
},
"second":{
    "id": "7"
},
"third":{
    "id": "4"
}
}

filter(lambda k: int(my_dict[k]['id']) in lst_ids, my_dict)
```

This will return `['second']` that is matched keys of dict.

Comment: Thank you but how do I exactly return the name? I initialized a variable that's equal to the filter (last line) and I get `<filter object at 0x10b083a90>`.

Comment: Ok! That's probably in Python3. You may use list(filter(....)) to get the list from filter object.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you! Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
l = [[1], [7], [9]]

dict = {
         "first":{"id": "0"},
         "second":{"id": "7"},
         "third":{"id": "4"}
        }

for i in l:
    for j in dict:
        if i[0] == int(dict[j]["id"]):
            print("Yay!")
        else:
            print("Nay!")
```

Comment: hmm, I got an error: `for j in dict:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this one-liner:

```
l = [[1], [7], [9]]

d = {"first":{ "id": "0"},
     "second":{"id": "7"},
    "third":{"id": "4"}}

l = [elem for elem in l if elem[0] in list(int(value['id']) for value in d.values())]

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[7]]
```

or alternatively you can do it using `filter`:

```
l = [[1], [7], [9]]

d = {"first":{ "id": "0"},
     "second":{"id": "7"},
    "third":{"id": "4"}}

resultValues = list(int(v['id']) for v in d.values())
l = list(filter(lambda i: i[0] in resultValues, l))

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
l = [[1], [7], [9]]

dict = {
"first":{
   "id": "0"
 },
"second":{
 "id": "7"
 },
 "third":{
    "id": "4"
 }
}
final_dicts = [{a:b} for a, b in dict.items() if [int(b['id'])] in l]
print "Yay!" if final_dicts else "Nay"
```

Output:

```
"Yay!"
```

Comment: Indeed! Yay! ;) Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Print `Yay!` and `Nay!` when -- convert to int and check in sub-list?

```
l = [[1], [7], [9]]

dict1 = {
"first":{
    "id": "0"
},
"second":{
    "id": "7"
},
"third":{
    "id": "4"
}
}

for i in l:
    for j in dict1:
        if int(dict1[j]['id']) in i:
            print("Yay!")
        else:
            print("Nay!")
```

Comment: This isn't really an improvement. You should be able to get rid of one of the loops by converting the list of elements `l` into a flat list.

Comment: This works for the input provided. What makes you think that flattening the list would improve the answer?